# I imported data from Excel. But i don’t know how to use the data using sentimentr package

Tags: r, excel, analysis

I am doing sentiment analysis using sentimentr package.

The data i am using are in the Excel, so I imported it to Rstudio.

But the problem is i am very new to R and I don’t know how to use sentimentr for analyzing the data.

There are 250 cells and in each cell there are sentences.

How can i analyze sentimental level for each cells?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: In the meantime, I would suggest you use `rio::import("file.xlsx")` to import your data from excel. Then you can follow the workflow on the Github page of the package: https://github.com/trinker/sentimentr#examples

Comment: Improved grammar.